# Select dates only within a range of dates in another sheet by animal ID

Tags: loops, date, if-statement, join, date-range

I have two data sheets, one containing bird movement data at 30 minute intervals and another containing date ranges within which the birds were nesting. I am only interested in looking at the movement data within the nesting ranges (using short dates only). Here's a simplified example of the data (I have thousands of rows IRL):

```
Data frame 1:
Bird_ID     Date        
A           4/5/2015 
A           4/20/2015
A           4/28/2015
B           5/6/2016
B           5/30/2016
C           3/4/2014
C           3/9/2014

Data frame 2:
Bird_ID     Nest_start     Nest_end
A           4/2/2015       4/15/2015
B           5/21/2016      6/3/2016
C           4/1/2014       4/15/2014
```

I am looking for output like this:

```
Data frame 1.1:
Bird_ID     Date        Keep (0=no, 1=yes)?  
A           4/5/2015    1
A           4/20/2015   0
A           4/28/2015   0
B           5/6/2016    0
B           5/30/2016   1
C           3/4/2014    0
C           3/9/2014    0
```

Columns are of different lengths. I have encountered errors following the methods from other posts (but sorry if this is a repeat anyway!). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First create your data, it's very important that when you import your table you add an argument `stringAsFactors=F` to your `read.table` or `read.csv`. This makes sure that R doesn't treat your dates as a factor.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Bird_ID = c(rep("A", 3), rep(c("B", "C"), each = 2)),
                  Date = c("4/5/2015", "4/20/2015", "4/28/2015",
                           "5/6/2016", "5/30/2016", "3/4/2014", "3/9/2014"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(Bird_ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  Nest_start = c("4/2/2015", "5/21/2016", "4/1/2014"),
                  Nest_end = c("4/15/2015", "6/3/2016", "4/15/2014"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Make your dates a date object

```
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df2$Nest_start <- as.Date(df2$Nest_start, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df2$Nest_end <- as.Date(df2$Nest_end, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Using `left_join` from `dplyr` package to join the two tables in one, since your two tables have same column names for the birds, no additional argument is required.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2)
```

Once your dates are properly declared as date objects, R allows you to do logical operators so you can create the Keep column. Here I make the column a TRUE/FALSE but you can transform it to numeric (1/0) by `as.numeric(df$Keep)`.

```
df$Keep <- df$Date <= df$Nest_end & df$Date >= df$Nest_start
df
```